# Bigcommerce API get all pages from a shop

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm working on an app for the bigcommerce platform and we need to retrieve the pages from shops using bigcommerce api. As I can see I can get the blog posts put there is no support for pages https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/content ? Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately there is not currently a way to get "pages" via the Bigcommerce API.